# Creating a footer for every page using R markdown

Tags: r-markdown, knitr, pandoc

I'm writing a document in R Markdown and I'd like it to include a footer on every page when I knit a PDF document. Does anyone have any idea on how to do this?

Comment: For the fancy stuff use LaTex not Markdown!

Comment: What @EDi said.  To use LaTeX with R, try knitr.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Yes, this question has been asked and answered here: [Adding headers and footers using Pandoc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139139/adding-headers-and-footers-using-pandoc). You just need to sneak a little LaTeX into the YAML header of your markdown document.

This markdown header does the trick:

```
---
title: "Test"
author: "Author Name"
header-includes:
- \usepackage{fancyhdr}
- \pagestyle{fancy}
- \fancyhead[CO,CE]{This is fancy header}
- \fancyfoot[CO,CE]{And this is a fancy footer}
- \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
output: pdf_document
---
```

Works for me with an Rmd file in [RStudio Version 0.98.1030 for Windows](http://www.rstudio.org/download/daily/desktop/windows/).

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to use the argument `includes` provided by `rmarkdown::pdf_document()` ([documentation](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/pdf-document.html#includes-1)). This allows you to keep the footer in a separate file. If your footer is defined in `footer.tex`, the header of your R Markdown file would look like this:

```
---
output:
  pdf_document:
    includes:
      after_body: footer.tex
---
```

This also assumes that `footer.tex` is in the same directory as the R Markdown file.

**Update:** The file `footer.tex` can contain any valid LaTeX that you want to be inserted at the end of your PDF document. For example, `footer.tex` could contain the following:

```
This \textbf{text} will appear at the end of the document.
```

Comment: Can you provide an example footer.tex? What are the minimal contents?

Comment: You can put any valid LaTeX in `footer.tex`. It will be inserted at the end of the PDF document. I updated my answer with an example.

Answer (score 0):

To manage the height of the footer, you can use the following:

```
date: '`r paste("Date:",Sys.Date())`'
output:
  pdf_document: 
    latex_engine: xelatex
header-includes:
      - \setlength{\footskip}{-50pt} # set the footer size
```

Keep Coding!