# Custom footer using R Markdown 2 and YAML for an HTML file

Tags: r, yaml, r-markdown

Using `R Markdown 2` and the YAML `include` statement I can easily customize the header section, the beginning and the end of the body section using `in_header`, `before_body` and `after_body` respectively, as described in the [RMarkdown docu](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/html_document_format.html#includes).

```
---
title: "Habits"
output:
  html_document:
    includes:
      in_header: header.html
      before_body: doc_prefix.html
      after_body: doc_suffix.html
---
```

How can I do the same for the `footer` section? (the output should be HTML)

A similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25329375/creating-a-footer-for-every-page-using-r-markdown) for PDF files and there is another answer for PDFs [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139139/adding-headers-and-footers-using-pandoc). Still, I cannot transfer the solution to HTML footers as my knowledge of pandoc is too limited.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround to manually inject HTML into the footer using R. I run this across all my documents after they have been generated to get a custom footer. Still a YAML-Pandoc solution as requested would be preferable.

```
library(stringr)
library(shiny)      # for HTML function
```

Function `inject_code_after_body_tag` will read in HTML file and add footer section after final body tag.

```
inject_code_after_body_tag <- function(file, include) 
{
  file.lines <- readLines(file, warn = FALSE, encoding = "UTF-8")
  include.lines <- readLines(include, warn = FALSE, encoding = "UTF-8")
  inc <- HTML(paste(include.lines, collapse = "\r\n"))
  l <- str_replace(file.lines,
                   perl("(?<=</body>)"),
                   inc)
  HTML(paste(l, collapse = "\r\n"))
}
```

Now, read in the file and inject code from footer.html

```
code <- inject_code_after_body_tag(file = "index.html", include = "include/footer.html")
```

Finally, write the new code back into the `index.html` file

```
writeLines(code, "index.html")
```