# Creating a footer for every page (including first!) using R markdown

Tags: latex, yaml, rstudio, r-markdown, pandoc

I'd like to add to the question [Creating a footer for every page using R markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25329375/creating-a-footer-for-every-page-using-r-markdown): how do I do this for the first page of the document in addition to all the following pages?

In RStudio, this code:

```
---
title: "Test"
author: "Author Name"
header-includes:
- \usepackage{fancyhdr}
- \usepackage{lipsum}
- \pagestyle{fancy}
- \fancyhead[CO,CE]{This is fancy header}
- \fancyfoot[CO,CE]{And this is a fancy footer}
- \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
output: pdf_document
---
\lipsum[1-30]
```

Produces this at the bottom of pg1:

[image: pg1]

and this (oddly, shouldn't this go on the left because of the `\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}`?) at the bottom of pg2:

[image: pg2]

and this at the bottom of pg3:

[image: pg3]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use

```
---
title: "Test"
author: "Author Name"
header-includes:
- \usepackage{fancyhdr}
- \usepackage{lipsum}
- \pagestyle{fancy}
- \fancyhead[CO,CE]{This is fancy header}
- \fancyfoot[CO,CE]{And this is a fancy footer}
- \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
- \fancypagestyle{plain}{\pagestyle{fancy}}
output: pdf_document
---
\lipsum[1-30]
```

which should override the `plain` page style - used on the first page with an issue of `\maketitle` - to be equivalent to `fancy`.

Remark that `\fancypagestyle{plain}{}` has the same effect as `\fancypagestyle{plain}{\pagestyle{fancy}}`.