# Dynamic header/footer in R-Markdown knit to word?

Tags: r, ms-word, r-markdown, knitr

I am generating a number of reports using an RMarkdown script. I would like to add a custom header/footer to the word-document output using a parameter, e.g. client_name. When I render the RMarkdown from a separate script, it loops through the list of clients and changes the data. I would like the header to update as well.

I have tried the answers from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46027246/in-r-markdown-create-header-footer-on-every-page-regardless-of-output-type-pdf?noredirect=1&lq=1) with no luck, as well as used a word reference document to set the header. However with the reference document, I can only set a static header that is not updated when the parameter changes.

Header should show:

Steve 
August 06, 2021 
Page X of 3

With "Steve" updated to a different name upon looping.

Here's what I have in my YAML:

```
---
title: "test doc"
author: 
- Author 1
- Author 2
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%B %d, %Y')`"
output: 
  word_document:
    reference_docx: test1.docx
params: 
  client: "Steve"
header-includes:
   - \usepackage{fancyhdr}
   - \usepackage{lipsum}
   - \pagestyle{fancy}
   - \fancyhead[LE,L0]{"params$client <br> `r format(Sys.time(), '%B %d, %Y')` <br> Page \thepage of 3"}
  
always_allow_html: true
---
```

Comment: I have this same question, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

I have implemented that in two steps:

1. Use a Word template (as reference_docx) that contains a dummy header (e.g., "mydummyheader").
2. To render the .rmd file, you use an R program (not interactively in R Studio).
3. In the same R program, after having created the Word document with your contents, you use the  `{officer}` library to replace your dummy header with the one that you want. Example code (also replacing a dummy footer):

```
    library(magrittr)
    library(officer)
    rmarkdown::render("mytest.Rmd", output_format = "word_document",
                       output_file = "mytest.docx")
    read_docx("mytest.docx") %>%              
    headers_replace_all_text("mydummyheader", "myrealheader") %>%               
    footers_replace_all_text("mydummyfooter", "myrealfooter") %>%
    print(target = "mytest_updated.docx")
```

Answer (score -1):

Use a **custom document property** with the name *ClientName*.
In the Header of the document, have a field `{ DocProperty ClientName}`.

Change the document property with your code.

See [How to use a single VBA procedure to read or write both custom and built-in Document Properties](https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/MacrosVBA/MixedDocProps.htm) by Word MVP Astrid Zeeland. This gives the vba for dealing with this.

Sorry, I know nothing about R-Markdown but expect that you will need the vba to change the Word document.

Comment: can you tell me how to call/update the custom document property in the r-script?

Comment: Sorry. I know Word and some vba, but not r-markdown/r-script. I expect that you will need the vba component to effect the change you want.