# Set and resize image as footer Rmarkdown title page

Tags: r, yaml, r-markdown, knitr, pandoc

I'm trying to set and resize an image as a footer in the title page of a markdown document.

I got the desired results in LaTex with:

```
\documentclass{article}


\title{Test}
\author{}
\date{}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}


\fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \fancyhf{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
    \lfoot{\includegraphics[width=400px]{footer.png}}
}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
\end{document}
```

But when I try to do the same thing in the Markdown document I get the following error:

Error in yaml::yaml.load(string, ...) : 
  Scanner error: while scanning a plain scalar at line 6, column 5 found a tab character that violate intendation at line 7, column 1
Calls:  ... parse_yaml_front_matter -> yaml_load_utf8 -> 
Execution halted

The code I have is:

```
---
title: "Test"
author: ""
header-includes:
- \usepackage{graphicx}
- \usepackage{fancyhdr}
- \fancypagestyle{plain}{
- \fancyhf{}
- \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
- \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
- \lfoot{\includegraphics[width=400px]{footer.png}}}
output: pdf_document
---
```

I've tried solutions like [Creating a footer for every page using R markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25329375/creating-a-footer-for-every-page-using-r-markdown) but it does't do the job for the title page.

Comment: Here is a similar issue: https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/1425. @mb21's answer below basically said you would need a pipe after `header-includes`, which is also what I said in the Github issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
---
title: "Test"
author: ""
header-includes: |
  \usepackage{graphicx}
  \usepackage{fancyhdr}
  \fancypagestyle{plain}{
  \fancyhf{}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
  \lfoot{\includegraphics[width=400px]{footer.png}}}
output: pdf_document
---
```

Comment: The pipe did make the picture appear but it wouldn't grow. In order to make the image as big as I wanted it I also had to specify its height with: `\lfoot{\includegraphics[width=400px, height=100px]{footer.png}}`.

Answer (score 0):

Yaml is a beast for escaping quotes and suchlike. You might want to create a separate file containing your latex header and just include that.

```
---
header-includes: yourfile.tex
---
```