# R Markdown pdf_document - footer without header

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

I am adding the following lines to add a customized footer to my pdf document, found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25329375/creating-a-footer-for-every-page-using-r-markdown?noredirect=1&lq=1).

```
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{fancyhdr}
  - \pagestyle{fancy}
  - \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{My fancy footer}
```

The issue is, I get also a header, which includes first and second chapter titles. As my chapter titles sometimes are long, they overlap. I wanted to ask **how to remove the header and keep the footer.** If it is easier, I am interested to keep only the first titles in the header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `\fancyhead{}` will get you an empty header.  Check the [user manual for the `fancyhdr` LaTeX package](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.pdf) to find out how to create custom headers and footers.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to remove *both* the header and the header horizontal rule, you can add the following to your doc preamble:

```
\fancyhead{}
\renewcommand{\headrule}{}
```

You can find a similar answer at [How to remove the top horizontal bar in fancyhdr](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13896/how-to-remove-the-top-horizontal-bar-in-fancyhdr).